# Seeded region growing in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to perform seeded region growing in matlab and can not find much help or documentation for this. The first step of my algorithm is to place a seed in the region to be segmented.

I have already calculated whether the object to be segmented is right or left orientated by doing

```
 total1=sum(BW3(:,[1:5]));%get the total of the first 5 columns in the image
 totalFirst=sum(total1); 
 display(totalFirst); %testing
 total2=sum(BW3(:,[end-4:end])); %get the total of the last 5 columns in the image
 totalLast=sum(total2);
 display (totalLast); %testing
```

Then if the sum of the first 5 cols is greater than the sum of the last 5 cols then the object is right orientated else it is left orientated.

So if the object is right orientated I need to place the seed in the first 5th row and 5th col of the image. If it is left orientated the seed must be placed in the last 5th row and fifth col.

Can anyone guide me with the syntax for actually planting the seed in these specified rows and cols?

Thanks

I am working with mammographic images and am trying to use seeded region growing to segement the pectoral muscle

Comment: We need more info about the `seed`. Is it just a scalar?

Comment: The seed needs to be placed inside the pectoral muscle of the mammogram which will either be in the first 5th row and col or the last 5th row and col

Comment: Since you would know the seed point based on `totalFirst` and `totalLast`, it seems like the problem is only left as a `seed-growing problem`, for which you can use something like this maybe? - http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35269-simple-single-seeded-region-growing

Comment: i am just unsure how to access the 5th row and 5th col... would i just set x=5,y =5? And how would i set this for the 5th last row and col?

Comment: The element at 5th row and 5th column would be `BW3(5,5)` and the element at 5th row and 5th from the final column would be `BW3(5,end-4)`.

Comment: Thanks! so when using the method you provided in the link above how can I pass in the x and y?

Comment: The function syntax is `function Phi = segCroissRegion(tolerance,Igray,x,y)`, thus `x` and `y` would be `5` and `5` respectively for the first case and then for the second case it would be `5` and `size(BW3,2)-4`.

Comment: thanks so much for your help! I am planting the seeds on a gray version of the image, however when I pass the image in, I am getting the error:
    Undefined function 'segCroissRegion' for input arguments of type
    'uint8'

Comment: You need to download the m-file from that link to your working directory. I am not sure though how would you pass on `BW3` into the function.

Comment: I have done that. I need to pass my image J into the function instead of BW3 as J is the grayscale image but i am getting the above error.

Comment: Did you download that m-file into your working directory yet? Do this - `which segCroissRegion` to see if you have that function in MATLAB path. Kindly check the output from `which segCroissRegion` and report it here.

Comment: yes I have it in my working directory. Output: C:\Users\CM\Desktop\SRG\segCroissRegion.m

Comment: Thanks have it running now! Turns out I was passing in the wrong image. Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Share your codes with the community maybe as an answer?

Comment: yes will do now. Can I just check what the tolerance in this method is ? Is it just a threshold?

Comment: Not sure, read up on that code at that link or contact that author if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

solved using the following code:

```
 if O==1  % 1 means right orientated
      x=5;
      y=5;
 else     % 0 means left orintated
     x=5;
     y=size(J,2)-4;
 end 

 %Added the method from mathworks to my project to perfrom seeded region growing
 %mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/ 

Phi=segCroissRegion(32,J,x,y);
```